# Countdown Javascript not working for smaller screens/mobile devices

Tags: javascript, php, html, countdown, jquery-countdown

The countdown Javascript I have for my website does not appear on smaller screens/mobile devices. It shows on my browser when in maximised view but not when I scale it down to a mobile size. Does anyone know what the issue could be? Everything else appears such as the text DAYS and HOURS.

Here is my HTML including the Javascript:

```
<div id="sale_banner" class="sale_banner">
        <p><?php echo $this->__('<strong>SALE now on!</strong> Up to 50% off on selected items - ') ?>
        <a style="color:white" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>sale"><u><strong> <?php echo $this->__('SHOP NOW!') ?></strong></u></a>
        </p>

        <div class="countdownList" style="text-align: center;">
            <ul>
                <li></li><span>Ends in:</span>
                <li><b><span id="days"</span></b>Days</li>
                <li><b><span id="hours"></span></b>Hours</li>
                <li><b><span id="minutes"></span></b>Minutes</li>
                <li><b><span id="seconds"></span></b>Seconds</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        const second = 1000,
            minute = second * 60,
            hour = minute * 60,
            day = hour * 24;

        let countDown = new Date('Jan 31, 2020 23:59:59').getTime(),
            x = setInterval(function() {

                let now = new Date().getTime(),
                    distance = countDown - now;

                document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
                    document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
                    document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
                    document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);

            });
    </script>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.countdownList li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 1em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height:16px;
  font-family: -apple-system,
  BlinkMacSystemFont,
  "Segoe UI",
  Roboto,
  Oxygen-Sans,
  Ubuntu,
  Cantarell,
  "Helvetica Neue",
  sans-serif;
}

.countdownList li span {
  display: block;
  font-family: -apple-system,
  BlinkMacSystemFont,
  "Segoe UI",
  Roboto,
  Oxygen-Sans,
  Ubuntu,
  Cantarell,
  "Helvetica Neue",
  sans-serif;
}
```

Here's the mobile equivalent (HTML):

```
<header class="mobile">

    <ul class="header-upper">
        <li class="left-upper">
            <div class="upper-links">
                <span class="icon-set white world nh">
                </span>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('dd_language') ?>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="middle">
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>" ><span></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="right-upper">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl(); ?>" class="upper-links">
                <p><?php echo $this->__('Cart') ?></p>
                <span class="icon-set basket">

                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="mobile-menu">
        <li class="col-xs-4">
            <div id="header-nav" class="header-nav skip-content">
                <div class="mobile-dropdown-menu" for="h-main-menu">
                    <span class="icon-set list"></span>
                    <p><?php echo $this->__('MENU') ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-4">
            <div id="" class="">
                <div class="mobile-dropdown-menu" for="h-search-menu">
                    <span class="icon-set search purple nh"></span>
                    <p><?php echo $this->__('SEARCH') ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-4">
            <div id="" class="">
                <div class="mobile-dropdown-menu" for="h-account-menu">
                    <span class="icon-set account purple nh"></span>
                    <p><?php echo $this->__('ACCOUNT') ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="hidden-menu clearfix">
        <li class="h-menu" id="h-main-menu"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?></li>
        <li class="h-menu" id="h-search-menu"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?></li>
        <li class="h-menu" id="h-account-menu"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="sale_banner" class="sale_banner">
        <p><?php echo $this->__('<strong>SALE now on!</strong> Up to 50% off on selected items - ') ?>
            <a style="color:white" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>sale"><u><strong> <?php echo $this->__('SHOP NOW!') ?></strong></u></a>
        </p>

        <div class="countdownList" style="text-align: center;">
            <ul>
                <li></li><span><i><?php echo $this->__('Ends in:') ?>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</i></span>
                <li><b><span id="X-days" </span> </b><?php echo $this->__('Days') ?> </li> <li><b><span id="X-hours"></span></b><?php echo $this->__('Hours') ?></li>
                <li><b><span id="X-minutes"></span></b><?php echo $this->__('Minutes') ?></li>
                <li><b><span id="X-seconds"></span></b><?php echo $this->__('Seconds') ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</header>
```

Comment: because you didn't use any media queries

Comment: I did use media queries but made no difference! The CSS for the DAYS and HOURS etc would show but not the actual countdown timer! It just seems that the javascript doesn’t get run....

Comment: Perhaps some of the javascript engines require the milliseconds in the [setInterval](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.bitdegree.org/learn/javascript-setinterval/amp) function?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you know what I could test out therefore?

Comment: Don't know the best way. Maybe something silly as adding a really simple test code as a snippet in your answer. And see if it runs on the mobile device? Assuming the add-blockers don't block it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As **LukStorms** suggest, `setInterval` require a milliseconds value on delay argument

> setInterval(code, **delay**);

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

I have changed almost nothing in your code:

```js
const one_Sec  = 1000
  ,   one_Min  = one_Sec * 60
  ,   one_Hour = one_Min * 60 
  ,   one_Day  = one_Hour * 24
  ,  countDown = new Date('Jan 31, 2020 23:59:59').getTime()
  ,  X_count   = { days    : document.getElementById('X-days')
                 , hours   : document.getElementById('X-hours')
                 , minutes : document.getElementById('X-minutes')
                 , seconds : document.getElementById('X-seconds')
                 }
  ;
setInterval(_=>
  {
  let now = new Date().getTime()
    , tim = countDown - now
    ;
  X_count.days.textContent    = Math.floor(tim / one_Day) 
  X_count.hours.textContent   = Math.floor((tim % one_Day ) / one_Hour )
  X_count.minutes.textContent = Math.floor((tim % one_Hour) / one_Min  )
  X_count.seconds.textContent = Math.floor((tim % one_Min ) / one_Sec  )
  }
  , one_Sec); // -> indicate here a delay value !
```

```css
.countdownList li {
  display        : inline-block;
  padding-right  : 1em;
  font-size      : 0.9em;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform : uppercase;
  line-height    : 16px;
  font-family    : -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
.countdownList li span {
  display     : block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sale_banner" class="sale_banner">
  <p>
    <strong>SALE now on!</strong> Up to 50% off on selected items -
  </p>

  <div class="countdownList" style="text-align: center;">
    <ul>
      <li></li><span>Ends in:</span>
      <li><b><span id="X-days" </span> </b>Days </li> <li><b><span id="X-hours"></span></b>Hours</li>
      <li><b><span id="X-minutes"></span></b>Minutes</li>
      <li><b><span id="X-seconds"></span></b>Seconds</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately it's still the same :(

Comment: It's strange that your snippet of code works when scaling down the browser.... I wonder what could be wrong with mine! :(

Comment: Ah right ok I see.... do you know of an alternative I could try? Thanks for your help with this

Comment: Unfortunately your code hasn’t made a difference, which is strange. Do you know what else I could try?

Comment: @Lloyd ! you wrong, my code made this difference. I use a global group of var to address this 4 Dom elements!

Comment: Your code works but it doesn’t solve my issue where the countdown doesn’t display on smaller screens/mobiles...

Comment: @Lloyd I'm just talking about my `const X_count` which has no equivalent in your code. Otherwise for your problem you should also introduce a try catch on this part which for me is suspect in your code

Comment: Yes you’re right. I have swapped my code for yours. That’s a good idea, I’ll do a try and catch to see what happens! This is so strange though that the countdown works perfectly for larger displays... what could change for it not to work for smaller screens? Hmmm

Comment: I’m totally puzzled by this :(

Comment: Oh my gosh I've just realised I never included the mobile HTML code on here!! So sorry about this! I've just edited my post to include the code. Hopefully this will narrow down the issue?